# The $p^k$-rank of a subgroup is no greater than the $p^k$-rank of the group.

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Recently I was given a handout containing (roughly) the following text:

> Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, and $p^k$ a prime power. The
>   $p^k$-rank of $A$ is defined to be
>   $$\operatorname{rank}_{p^k}(A):=\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_p}(p^{k-1}A/p^kA).$$
>   It is immediate from the definition that for any subgroup $B\subseteq A$
>    and any prime power $p^k$ 
>   $$\operatorname{rank}_{p^k}(B)\leq\operatorname{rank}_{p^k}(A).$$

However, I do not see how this follows from the definition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity we consider only the case $k=1$. We have to show $\dim_{\mathbb F_p}(B/pB) \leq \dim_{\mathbb F_p}(A/pA)$. Note that this is equivalent to $|B/pB| \leq |A/pA|$.
Consider the exact sequence
$$0 \to {}_pA \to A \to pA \to 0$$
where $A \to pA$ is multiplication by $p$ and ${}_p A = \{ a \in A : pa = 0 \}$ is its kernel. The exactness implies $|A| = |{}_pA| |pA|$ and similarly $|B| = |{}_pB| |pB|$. Since ${}_p B \subseteq {}_p A$, we get
$$|B/pB| = |B|/|pB| = |{}_pB| \leq |{}_p A| = |A|/|pA| = |A/pA|.$$